# How do I translate "firmware" to Russian? / Как перевести firmware на русский язык?

Tags: перевод, информатика

Как красиво перевести "firmware"?

- software - программное обеспечение;
- hardware - аппаратное обеспечение;
- firmware - ??? обеспечение?

Достаточно ли литературен термин "прошивка"?

Comment: How about *системное программное обеспечение*?

Comment: It's "system software". The opposite is "application software" - "прикладное программное обеспечение".

Comment: Я видел в литературе название "микрокод", правда это были достаточно старые книги.

Comment: @Vi. I realize my translation is not unambiguous for a scientific paper but it should be ok for a hardware manual. Should have said that in the first place.

Comment: @DmitryOlyenyov, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вариант как ответ.

Comment: Обновление программы? Красиво (как требовалось) но - маловразумительно. Как впрочем и "прошивка". Oh poor Russian language.

Comment: @Arhad, Раньше он был ответом, его удалили.

Comment: Вообще, как минимум в ранние годы, но частично и все еще, существовало как бы два языка — жаргон, частично свой, частично заимствованный из английского, и официальные термины, которые никто вне официального контекста не употреблял. Ряд: `флоп` — `флоппи-диск` (floppy disc) — `дискета` — `накопитель на гибких магнитных дисках` often abbreviated as `НГМД`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Официальный термин, зафиксированный в словарях, — «Микропрограмма» (наравне с упомянутым выше «программно-аппаратным обеспечением»). Но это слово употребляется, пожалуй, лишь в отношении микроконтроллеров и прочих устройств, где эта самая микропрограмма физически прошивается программатором.
Как бы ни было неприятно пуристам, «прошивка» — уже, похоже, действительно литературный термин.

Comment: Пуристам-то как раз грех огорчаться, что в русском прижилось слово _прошивка_, а не _фирмварь_, например (в других языках, кстати, если верить Википедии, подходящего слова не нашлося). У слова _микропрограмма_ же (оставим в стороне то, что оно действительно частично синонимично «прошивке») есть точное английское соответствие и это не _firmware_, а _microcode_.

Comment: Дмитрий, я не про тех пуристов :) Я про тех, которые до сих пор пишут «брандмауэр», хотя это слово никто уже не употребляет в принципе.

Comment: Сегодня мне пришёл заказанный MP3-плеер. Так там в инструкции таки микропрограмма. Так что, думаю, можно употреблять и "микропрограмму" тоже, хотя для меня это несколько странновато: микропрограмма, которая на самом деле представляет собой кучу файлов общим объёмом несколько десятков мегабайт.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny but the official term for firmware is actually "программно-аппаратное обеспечение" or "встроенное обеспечение". But, like all the terms you've mentioned, it is very non-typical to use such terms anywhere except may be official documents.

So yes, "прошивка" is OK in almost all cases and currently is not limited by colloquial speech.

Comment: А вы не могли бы найти хоть один пример, где _программно-аппаратное обеспечение_ употреблялось бы в этом смысле, а не как синоним «программное и аппаратное обеспечение» (ср. с термином _программно-аппаратный комплекс_). Где вы вообще его взяли? Я понимаю, что русский язык в принципе позволяет трактовать _программно-аппаратный_ как «промежуточный меж программным и аппаратным», что и есть _firmware_, но тем не менее, по-моему, это фантазия составителя словаря, не подкрепленная ни малейшей практикой.

Answer (score 0):

Если непременно необходимо использовать что-то иное от "прошивка", то я бы перевёл "firmware" как "базовое программное обеспечение", так как по сути это такой расширенный "BIOS".

Answer (score 0):

Большой англо-русский политехнический словарь:
(изд. "Русский язык", Москва, 1991)
**firmware 1.** микропрограммное обеспечение, микропрограммы **2.** программы, записанные в ПЗУ **3.** аппаратно-реализованное программное обеспечение

Answer (score -5):

Мне кажется `прошивка` - чересчур кустарно. Так говорят в шаражках КГБ между собой клерки, но не учёные. Это не литературный термин.

По аналогии

- Software - Программное обеспечени
- Hardware - Оборудование / аппаратное обеспечение
- Malware - Вредоносное программное обеспечение
- Firmware - Програмное обеспечение оборудования

Comment: И много ли вы клерков в шарашках видели? Что по факту, то все ровно наоборот: «прошивка» происхождением из сугубо технического жаргона.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov если вы видите у кого-то опечатку, неважно случайную ли или безграмотную, просто поправьте, не стоит в комментах делать на этом упор. Я поправил ответ и тоже заминусовал, потому что он неправильный.

Comment: Не уловил мысль о клерках в шарашках КГБ. Шарашек уже нет, клерков в них не было, а про firmware в те времена никто не мог говорить - все было теплое и ламповое.