# Как возникло слово "прошивка" в смысле firmware (программа в телефоне, читалке, другом гаджете)?

Tags: этимология, информатика

В обсуждении вопроса о [переводе firmware](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/6965/551) на русский язык мнения о слове "прошивка" разделились. Кто-то утверждают что это слэнг, другие утверждают что это уже литературное слово.

Но у меня возник вопрос - каким образом слово "прошивка" стало обозначать программу, которая управляет устройством и которую не так-то просто поменять, хотя и можно это сделать затратив дополнительные усилия.

Итак, почему "прошивка", что здесь "шьется"?

Поиск слова прошивка в Национальном корпусе показывает что слово изначально было связано с шитьем и украшением одежды.

Затем это слово упоминается в смысле "проделывание и обработка отверстий в металле", затем "прожигание отверстий лазером в рубине".

Связано ли появление слова "прошивка" с проделыванием каких-либо отверстий для сохранения программы? Или с выжиганием лазером "лишней" электроники (контактов, транзисторов и т.п.)? Или оно каким-либо образом переосмысливает другой процесс из техники?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Действительно, для программирования компьютеров (или как их тогда называли ЭВМ) использовались методы основанные на идее пробивания отверстий (перфокарты, перфоленты) или выжигания [лишних связей](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROM). И в принципе здесь была возможна "коррекция" (перепрошивка) - иногда можно было изменить записанную таким образом информацию пробив дополнительные отверстия или удалив существующие связи.

Однако, как оказалось, аналогия была взята прямо из [процесса шитья](http://zhevak.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85/), а не как термин из другой технической отрасли.

Дело в том, что еще до использования микросхем, один из вариантов памяти для вычислительных машин был основан на использовании "ферритовых сердечников", - проще говоря, [намагниченных металлических колец](http://www.computer-museum.ru/books/ural_ferit/first.htm). Программирование постоянной памяти, основанной на этой технологии, состояло в том, что специальной иглой пропускали проволоку только в те кольца, которые должны были хранить логическую "1".

Чтобы монтажницам было легче находить нужные кольца, на матрицу этих колец наклеивали кальку со схемой и работницы "пришивали" проволокой эту кальку к основе используя иглу. Прямая ассоциация с шитьем привела к появлению слова "прошивка", а затем это слово стало официальным термином. Вот например, статьи из [Русско-английского политехнического словаря](http://polytechnic_ru_en.enacademic.com/):

> [прошивка матрицы запоминающего устройства](http://polytechnic_ru_en.enacademic.com/46708) weaving of a wire through a matrix
>
> [наносить обмотку на феррит методом прошивки вчт.](http://polytechnic_ru_en.enacademic.com/46706/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) — wind a core by a sewing technique

Интересно что здесь возможна и "перепрошивка" - достаточно удалить старую проволоку и пропустить новую через другие ферритовые сердечники.

<sup>Кстати в Википедии есть статья о [прошивке](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в которой тоже упоминаются П- и Ш-образные ферритовые сердечники (т.е. не кольца), но это уже более поздняя технология.</sup>

---

Судьбу этого слова после того как ферритовые сердечники вышли из употребления я не проследил, хотя на радиофоруме [нашелся пост](http://www.radioscanner.ru/forum/topic35682.html#msg532491), в котором автор рассказывает как прошивал память на ферритовых сердечниках в конце 90-х.

Но в 1994 году в журнале ["Радиолюбитель" № 2/94](http://www.gus.biysk.ru/Radiolubitel/1994/1994-02.pdf) в статье об апгрейде компьютера "Спектрум-48" до "Спектрум-128" (страницы 9 и 10) слово "прошивка" употребляется очень активно:

> Прошивка 27256 в схемах рис. 3 (в,г) также должна иметь в начальных адресах "нулевую" страницу, но если это не так и нет возможности "перешить" микросхему, то сигнал A14 (ROM) необходимо проинвертировать, например, через К555ЛН1.
>
> Для "маленьких" контроллеров лучше применить схемы рис. 3(в,г) с установкой дополнительных микросхем DD47 с прошивкой TR-DOS.
>
> В остальных случаях лучше иметь прошивку ПЗУ с функцией TAPE TESTER, которая позволит, кроме всего прочего, правильно настроить магнитофон при вводе программ.

С 2002 года Национальный корпус находит слово "прошивка" в различных популярных журналах: для автолюбителей ("Автопилот") и о дизайне интерьеров ("Homes & Gardens"):

> Если только на него не установили блок управления впрыском чешского производства: потомки бравого солдата Швейка намудрили с «прошивкой» ― на Octavia c немецкими моторами он иногда «глючит». [Николай Качурин. Гей, славяне! (2002) // «Автопилот», 2002.06.15]
>
> К слову, эта прошивка неважно поддерживает и протокол GPRS. [Николай Качурин. Опыт: Воспользоваться услугой GPRS // «Автопилот», 2002]
>
> Непременно сверьте серийный номер телефона, так называемый IMEI, в трех местах: на коробке, на самом аппарате под аккумулятором и в прошивке ― этот номер вызывается командой *#06# с клавиатуры любого мобильного телефона. [Вадим Логинов. Ищу связь, брак не предлагать (2002) // «Homes & Gardens», 2002.04.15]

А журнал "Наука и жизнь", который славится своим консерватизмом по поводу терминологии, тем не менее использует это слово в статьях, опубликованных в 2006 и 2007 году (по-моему это признание его литературности):

> В одном из окон программа может сообщить вам, что новых версий прошивки для вашего смартфона пока нет, и предложит переустановить вашу версию. [Р. Бокоев. Смартфон или телефон? // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]
>
> Во-первых, здесь имеется некоторый объем постоянной памяти (обычно от 16 до 48 Мб), где хранится изначальная «прошивка» операционной системы и стандартных приложений, и эта информация используется для загрузки системы при первом включении или при полном перезапуске КПК. [Д. Усенков. Электронный помощник в кармане // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]

Comment: Мощное исследование) А я-то всегда считал, что прошивка в смысле firmware пошла от процесса выжигания программатором) Как-то не задумывался, что это может иметь хоть что-то общее с шитьём иглой. Спасибо!